# How to make a wpf application auto at computer start up programmatic ally?

Tags: wpf, startup, autorun

How to make a WPF application automatically run at computer start up programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options:

1. You can put a link in the start up folder
2. If you only want it to start up for the current user you can put a entry in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
3. If you want it to start for all users you can put a entry in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Answer (score 1):

Place the executable in the Startup folder?

Add the executable to the Run key in the registry?

Answer (score -1):

Did you really mean at computer **startup** as opposed to when the user logs on?

If so, you'll either need to use Windows' [automatic logon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) feature or you'll need to integrate with the login screen, which may mean [developing your own GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Windows XP and below or using the [Credential Provider Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) for Vista and above.

There is no reason you can't use WPF in a GINA or a Credential Provider.

If you don't want to run your application until the user logs on, just use the Startup folder or the Run key in the registry.